# data inside tag is missing in jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

i am trying to scrap data from https://www.hackerearth.com/
on the right side there is **live events**.if i see the source code in browser of this **live events** then we can see whole of the data.(see pic)[developer view in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0B81.png)

now this is my jsoup code :

```
Document doc=Jsoup.connect("https://www.hackerearth.com").get();
System.out.println(doc.html());
```

in output,we can see all of the html of page but all of the data inside div of live events is missing.
in output i have empty div tag.

```
<div id="live-events-trigger-data"></div>
```

where as in pic you can see that there is huge data in this div tag.
so how do i get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the source of your page in the web browser you will see the reason at the end:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#header-notif-icon-trigger').click();
    $('#live-events-trigger').click();
    // show kone ge widget if not visited
        $(window).load( function () {
             var hackathon_visit_cookie = readCookie('fintech_valley_hackathon_cookie');
             if (!hackathon_visit_cookie) {
                $('#custom_hackathon_widget').show();
             }
        });
        $(document).on('click', '#custom_hackathon_widget .hack-link', function(e) {
            createCookie('fintech_valley_hackathon_cookie', 'true', 180);
            $('#custom_hackathon_widget').fadeOut('slow');
        });
});
</script>
```

You cannot execute JavaScript code with Jsoup. If you want to execute JavaScript, use [HTMLUnit](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit) or [Selenium](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java).